# JavaScript Form and Calculating the Score

Tags: javascript, forms

I have to some exercise for my javascript class.

The task I have to finish is creating a simple form where users are able to choose 1 option for each question, and once they have chosen selected options, the form will display their score.

```
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="">
<fieldset id="controls">
  <p>Do you like chocolate?
  <label>Yes a lot </label>
  <input type="radio" name="choco" id="alot" value="Alot" checked="true">
  <label>Not that much </label>
  <input type="radio" name="choco" id="notMuch" value="NotMuch">
  <label>No, but still I don't mind eating it sometimes </label>
  <input type="radio" name="choco" id="noSometimes" value="NoSometimes">
  <label>No, I hate it </label>
  <input type="radio" name="choco" id="hate" value="Hate">
  </p>
  <p>Do you prefer chocolate cake or carrot cake?
  <label>chocolate </label>
  <input type="radio" name="cake" id="chocolate" value="Chocolate" checked="true">
   <label>Carrot </label>
  <input type="radio" name="cake" id="carrot" value="Carrot">
  <label>Both</label>
  <input type="radio" name="cake" id="both" value="Both">
   <label>None </label>
  <input type="radio" name="cake" id="none" value="None">
  </p>

  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="Calculate" id="calculate" value="Calculate" />
  </p>
```

So I thought I will create a very short form that asks the user 2 question, to find out how much the person likes or dislikes chocolate.

And for the calculation I did the following coding:

```
var numericalValues = new Array();
numericalValues["Alot"]= 4;
numericalValues["NotMuch"]= 2;
numericalValues["NoSometimes"]= 3;
numericalValues["Hate"]= 0;
numericalValues["Chocolate"]= 4;
numericalValues["Carrot"]= 0;
numericalValues["Both"]= 2;
numericalValues["None"]= 0;


function getScoreChoco(){
    var scoreChoco = 0;
    var form = document.forms["form"];
    var choco = form.elements["choco"];
    for(var i=0; i<choco.length; i++){
        if(choco[i].checked){
            totalScore = numericalValues[choco[i].value];
            break;
        }
    }
    return scoreChoco;
}

function getScoreCake(){
    var scoreCake = 0;
    var form = document.forms["form"];
    var cake = form.elements["diabetic1"];
    for(var i=0; i<cake.length; i++){
        if(cake[i].checked){
            totalScore = numericalValues[cake[i].value];
            break;
        }
    }
    return scoreCake;
}

function getTotal(){
    var totalScore = getScoreCake() + getScoreChoco()

    document.getElementById('calculate').innerHTML =
                                  "Your total score is: "+totalScore;
}
```

And the code is not working, help please :(

[Here's my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZgjTB/)

Comment: jsFiddle it and let us know what you expect

Comment: @blue, what does jsFiddle it mean?

Comment: @user3344405 jsFiddle means [that](http://jsfiddle.net/) - a site where you can show us a live-demo of your code.

Comment: @morten.c thank you for the explanation, I did it: http://jsfiddle.net/ZgjTB/

Comment: not sure if I deleted the semi-colon while editing your post or if it was missing all along. .. in your getTotal function the first line.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about doing the poster's homework.

Comment: @DourHighArch - homework questions are not necessarily off-topic - it matters whether the question is written well.

Comment: @user3344405 - your question needs some clarification - "not working" is pretty broad. What exactly is not working? Does it crash? Output the wrong thing? Something else? This information, along with what you've tried to resolve the problem will be most valuable in us being able to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made few changes:

1. I assumed that you want to caluculate in javascript so i remove submit button from the form and change it with simple button with id 'calulate'
2. Then I bound onclick event for buton ('calculate') to getTotal function
3. in function getScoreChoco and getScoreCake i used you variable for returning score becouse you was using totalscore property of the window object not variable defined for return result

I paste javascript code becouse i have problem with jsFiddle

```
var numericalValues = new Array();
numericalValues["Alot"]= 4;
numericalValues["NotMuch"]= 2;
numericalValues["NoSometimes"]= 3;
numericalValues["Hate"]= 0;
numericalValues["Chocolate"]= 4;
numericalValues["Carrot"]= 0;
numericalValues["Both"]= 2;
numericalValues["None"]= 0;


function getScoreChoco()
{
var scoreChoco = 0;
var form = document.forms["form"];
var choco = form.elements["choco"];
for(var i=0; i<choco.length; i++)
{
    if(choco[i].checked)
    {
    scoreChoco = numericalValues[choco[i].value];
    break;
    }

}
return scoreChoco;
};

function getScoreCake()
{
var scoreCake = 0;
var form = document.forms["form"];
var cake = form.elements["cake"];

for(var i=0; i<cake.length; i++)
{
  if(cake[i].checked)
  {
  scoreCake = numericalValues[cake[i].value];
  break;
  }

}
return scoreCake;
};


function getTotal()
{

var totalScore = getScoreCake() + getScoreChoco();


document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
                              "Your total score is: "+totalScore;

}

document.getElementById('calculate').onclick=getTotal;
```

**EDIT** And HTML Code

```
<form id="form" name="form">
<fieldset id="controls">
<p>Do you like chocolate?
<label>Yes a lot </label>
<input type="radio" name="choco" id="alot" value="Alot" checked="true">

<label>Not that much </label>
<input type="radio" name="choco" id="notMuch" value="NotMuch">
<label>No, but still I don't mind eating it sometimes </label>
<input type="radio" name="choco" id="noSometimes" value="NoSometimes">

 <label>No, I hate it </label>
<input type="radio" name="choco" id="hate" value="Hate">
</p>
<p>Do you prefer chocolate cake or carrot cake?
<label>chocolate </label>
<input type="radio" name="cake" id="chocolate" value="Chocolate" checked="true">

<label>Carrot </label>
<input type="radio" name="cake" id="carrot" value="Carrot">

<label>Both</label>
<input type="radio" name="cake" id="both" value="Both">

<label>None </label>
<input type="radio" name="cake" id="none" value="None">
</p>

<p>
  <input type="button" name="Calculate" id="calculate" value="Calculate" />
</p>
    <p id="result"></p>

    </form>
```

Comment: @ŁukaszSzewczak, now I am just checking everything, I need like 2-3 minutes, then I might ask 1 more question or simply choose your answer as final answer :)

Comment: @ŁukaszSzewczak, okay I have tested the javascript code using my original HTML code posted in the first post, but it didn't work....Do you mind posting the HTML code, you used as well?

Comment: @ŁukaszSzewczak, also, in the task it says I have to have a submit button, so I will keep it.

Comment: @user3344405 if You need this submit button, then You must put 'return false' to the end of the getTotal function to prevent posting this form on server

Comment: @ŁukaszSzewczak, before I will go to bed and sleep, I need to tell you something (I know I will sounds like a total noob, but it's ok) html as well as the javascript code is working perfectly on the http://jsfiddle.net/ but whenever I copy and paste it into my notepad++ it's not working although I copied the html code into the body part of the html and also did external attachment the javascript code.

Comment: @user3344405 do not worry, it's better to always ask. if You put Your code into external file there is few optionios you can do: 1. You can to insert link to external javascript file on the end of your html file before ending body tag, this is becouse if You have js file attached on the header of the html document your javascript code won't find button with id 'calculate' becouse it was not yet rendered,

Comment: @user3344405 Or You can remove from js file last line 'document.getElementById('calculate').onclick=getTotal;' and assing getTotal function directly to the button tag in html code '  <input type="button" name="Calculate" id="calculate" value="Calculate"  onclick="getTotal()"/>'

Comment: @Łukasz Szewczak, I am sorry, I guess I was a bit sleepy, nope, I actually didn't need the submit button, just 1 button called calculate, and I already got it in the html :) So thanks, my problem was for some reason if I copy and paste the html as well as javascript code into the notepad++ , the javascript code is displaying nothing,although this code works by Fiddle perfectly. The javascript console gives me 2 error messages which I don't understand: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND  and 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null .

Comment: @Łukasz Szewczak, dear Lukasz, sorry to disturb you, I just wanted to let you know, right now I know what my mistake was, I put the js file into the head part, but I should have done to the bottom part of the body. Again thank you very much for your help.